# How to define a servlet in the deployment descriptor using Eclipse Mars?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am currently doing a simple project using Eclipse Mars, but how do I define a servlet in the deployment descriptor so that the web application can know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an entry similar to the following in your `web.xml` irrespective of what version of any IDE that you use.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name> <!-- You can use any name -->
    <servlet-class>com.package.servlets.MyFirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name> <!-- This should be the same as the name defined in the previous tag -->
    <url-pattern>/myserv</url-pattern> <!-- This will be the url that you will use to access your servlet -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

The URL that you will use to access your servlet will be `http://host:port/appName/myserv`

If you are using Servlet3.0, then you have the option to use annotations as well. In this case you don't need to edit anything in the web.xml. Simply annotate your class with `@WebServlet` as below

```
com.package.servlets

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/myserv")
public class MyFirstServlet{
    // servlet specific code here
}
```